# JSDoc wont work with this example script, why?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

im trying to get the hang of **JSDoc 3.5** with **nodejs** and i made a little script to test it. I am using JSDoc as is without any change or custom config.

Here is the script :

```
/**
 * TestLib
 * A simple test for jsdoc to parse
 * @author MMAI
 * @version 0.1
 * @returns {TestLib} The static reference of this lib
 */
 'use strict';
function TestLib() {
    var api = {};

    /**
     * testMethod()
     * adds two arguments together and returns the results
     * @type {Function}
     * @param {Number} a_arg1 The first number in the addition
     * @param {Number} a_arg2 The second number in the addition
     * @returns {Number} The result of the addition
     */
    api.testMethod = function (a_arg1, a_arg2) {
        return a_arg1 + a_arg2;
    };

    //api set
    return api;
}
```

For now only the global function **TestLib** is documented in global.html, but not **testMethod**. Does this mean that JSDoc won't work good with this kind of coding? Or am i missing something here?

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this issue.

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found what i needed. I needed to use @namepsace and @alias with my inner method.

```
/**
 * @namespace
 * TestLib
 * A simple test for jsdoc to parse
 * @author MMAI
 * @version 0.1
 * @returns {TestLib} The static reference of this lib
 */
 'use strict';
function TestLib() {
    var api = {};

    /**
     * @alias TestLib.testMethod
     * adds two arguments together and returns the results
     * @type {Function}
     * @param {Number} a_arg1 The first number in the addition
     * @param {Number} a_arg2 The second number in the addition
     * @returns {Number} The result of the addition
     */
    api.testMethod = function (a_arg1, a_arg2) {
        return a_arg1 + a_arg2;
    };

    //api set
    return api;
}
```